# Create intelligent Pages and Columns Layout in Angular

Tags: angularjs, layout, printing, display

i'm trying to achieve a specific layout to display a list and I'm completely stuck on how i should approach this.

The background:
I'm developing a browser app to manage lists. Users work with a one-column list and switch category tabs to change the data displayed.
When the user has finished editing the list i want to print it out and therefor switch from the one-column layout to a multi-column layout, that simulates page breaks.

For example:

```
|------------------------| Page1
|category1   | -item     |
|-item       | -item     |
|-item       |           |
|-item       | category3 |
|-item       | -item     |
|            | -item     |
|category2   | -item     |
|-item       | -item     |
|-item       | -item     |
|-item       | -item     |
|------------------------|

|------------------------|Page2
|-item       | -item     |
|-item       | -item     |
|-item       |           |
|-item       | category5 |
|-item       | -item     |
|            | -item     |
|category4   | -item     |
|-item       | -item     |
|-item       | -item     |
|-item       | -item     |
|------------------------|

....
```

And i'd also need this columns to break "intelligent". Things like little "reminder" category tags whenever a page breaks, avoid new category headers at the bottom of a column without entrys below it etc.

I set up a sample List Plnkr here.
http://plnkr.co/edit/bBnO01x6OHuRehyhdNC4?p=preview
But since i don't know where to start it's just a list at the moment:)

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TestController as ctrl">
<page size="A4">
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="category in ctrl.data">
    <h3>{{category.categoryName}}</h3>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in category.items">
      {{item.name}}  
      </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</page>
```

Actually it's just something that regards view logic and therefor should be handled in the template. I wish this could be done there , but I don't see a way at the moment.

I can only think of ways of doing this in the controller or directives.

Does anyone have an idea how to tackle this?

### Update

In my attempt to try and solve this, i've come to this strange point (but can't think of a better way): plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/bBnO01x6OHuRehyhdNC4?p=preview

```
<ul ng-show="hide===true">
 <li ng-repeat="category in printCtrl.data">
  <h3 get-height item="category"
   ng-class="{endOfColumn:category.endOfColumn}">
   {{category.categoryName}}h:{{category.height}}
  </h3>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in category.items"
       get-height item="item"
       ng-class="{endOfColumn:item.endOfColumn}">
       {{item.name}}h:{{item.height}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul ng-repeat="column in printCtrl.columnData">
  <li ng-repeat="category in column">
    <h3
    ng-class="{endOfColumn:category.endOfColumn}">
    {{category.categoryName}}h:{{category.height}}
    </h3>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in category.items"
        ng-class="{endOfColumn:item.endOfColumn}">
          {{item.name}} h:{{item.height}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I'm ng-hiding my list first to find the height of each list element.
Then i use this information to add the heights till it reaches a certain value, and split the list in parts.

It kinda works, but how can i do this without displaying and hiding information, just to get to the element height.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve the exact layout *in* the browser? Or are you trying to achieve that layout just in the printout?

Comment: I'm trying to create it in the browser. The printout should look the same, but i'm aware that there probably will be some minor differences. My main concern is, if such complex layouts can be achieved via angular templates only or if in this case jquery is the way to go.

Comment: At the moment i'm just trying to find out when a (list or whatever) element leaves the page, to create a pagebreak. and start ng repeat at this element on the next page again. I keep the column stuff for later.

Answer (score 0):

If you were only interested in a preview of 1 page, you could use CSS to acheive the layout.

See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp

You could try CSS3 directives like this:

```
page {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  padding: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
  column-count: 2;
```

}

[image]

Perhaps you could use that combined with jQuery/JS code finding where the breaks occur in columns 3, 5, ... to implement something to surround those elements with page elements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But either way I'd have to process a lot of the actual display logic inside the model, to find out where a new page starts. What puzzles me is, this: I've got to render the list first, to find out the elements height, and than re-render it again. I can't get my head around this.